# Tensor Calculus Second Order Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

I'm learning tensor calculus by myself through lectures and texts, and I'm presented with the problem of finding the first and second order derivatives of a scalar function of three variables that vary with two parameters. I label the function $f(x^i(\mu^{\alpha}))$ where $i$ runs from one to three and $\alpha$ runs from one to two, setting the $x^i$ as the variables that change with the parameters $\mu^{\alpha}$. Geometrically this represents a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I also set forth the convention for this problem will be to take Latin indices to run from one to three ( coordinates ) and Greek indicies to run from one to two ( parameters ).

I first begin by finding the general form of the first derivatives of $f$ with respect to arbitrary coordinates. Brute forcing them with multivariate calculus I get: $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu^1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \mu^1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial \mu^1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^3} \frac{\partial x^3}{\partial \mu^1} $$

The same follows for differentiation w.r.t. the second parameter as well. The pattern makes itself clear and allows me to combine both of those derivatives into the single statement:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu^{\alpha}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \mu^{\alpha}}$$

following the Einstein Summation Convention. As for the second derivative, I attempted to carry on the tensor notation and not derive results from multivariable calculus. Beginning with a first rank, covariant tensor, I take the derivative of the previous expression with respect to the parameters again, but using a different index to include all possible second order derivative combos. In symbols: $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu^{\beta}}( \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu^{\alpha}}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu^{\beta}}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \mu^{\alpha}}) $$

Applying the chain rule--if done correctly--I get $$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \mu^{\alpha} \partial \mu^{\beta}} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \mu^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \mu^{\alpha}} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial^2 x^i}{\partial \mu^{\alpha} \partial \mu^{\beta}} $$ a second order covariant tensor. Is this correct?

Comment: one of the $i$ in the last formula should be $j$ to comply tensor notation standards

Comment: Would that not result in a third rank tensor where we should have second rank?

Comment: no, because is contracting

Comment: With what >______< Are you saying we'll have two contractions one with respect to j and the other i?

Comment: ....... yes ...

Comment: Is it correct now after the edits?

Comment: All good! So in general, where I had 4 of the index in summation pairs, I should switch to using another letter for the next summation pairs?

Comment: yes, because they are different summations. One never uses repeated indexes both above nor both below.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info!

Comment: maybe you would like to visit my contributions and in case you like it.. you could upvote me ;)

Comment: Oh, and when doing explicit calculations, since there's a double summation, my Greek indices remain fixed and I take j fixed and sum over i and then fix i and sum over j, correct?

Comment: Yes, "alone" indexes are immutable. The "not alone" ones are as a dummy variables that can be developed as you say

Comment: And as far as not doubling up on terms, I find it obvious that one wouldn't have to repeat terms where i=j, but would I have an i=1,j=2 and an i=2,j=1 even though their order in this particular case is irrelevant?

Comment: let me exemplify: $a_{ij}b^{ij}=a_{11}b^{11}+a_{12}b^{12}+a_{21}b^{21}+a_{22}b^{22}$

Comment: Perfect. Precisely what I was expecting! Thank you again for the clarification! I feel I understand better how to explicitly calculate these quantities!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aforementioned line of reasoning and equations presented in the question are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check Kryszig's *Differential Geometry* (Dover, 1959) on p. 156. Though the deduction process is not indicated, a generic expression in index notation is reported which could be useful to corroborate your procedure.